# How to update my BIOS

Tags: bios

I have a computer having HCL Pegatron motherboard having Intel G41 Express Chipset. I also have Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 processor and 2 GB DDR2 RAM and 250 GB SATA Hard Disk. I want to run VirtualBox on my PC. For this my processor also has the Intel VT-X technology. But my BIOS does not allow me to enable it. So I need to update my BIOS to a newer version. But I can't find support on the HCL website for this. My current BIOS version/date is IPM41_GS 080015, 26-02-2009. Can someone help my to find a BIOS for my computer from a trusted source.

Comment: If the manufacturer's website doesn't have BIOS update files you probably won't find them... easily. Your hardware specs seem a bit outdated. I don't think you will have much luck with virtualization. Is the full model of your motherboard just "HCL Pegatron" I find that a bit short and that only makes the search more difficult.

Comment: This is the closest I can find that might match your chipset https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/43798/Intel-Desktop-Board-DG41CN

Comment: When I look for motherboard model under Windows 10 System Information, it says 'Not Available'

Comment: Take your computer apart and physically look for fine print on your motherboard. You can find the model and make there. Alternatively try a free software called CPU-Z.

Comment: My motherboard model is IPM41

Comment: I found the following by searching for that model and adding "BIOS"
https://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/download-bios/1462523/

Comment: I did find another website that has a modded BIOS file, though I couldn't understand what the changes were. Since it's a forum perhaps you can have some luck there.
https://www.overclock.net/forum/5-intel-cpus/1670353-hp-pegatron-ipm41-d3-bios-mod-file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To formalize the comments into an answer :

**You need to gather the model of the motherboard. To do so, there are two options.**

1. [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), a free software that reads all sorts of hardware information.
2. Open your case and search for fine print with the model and make of your motherboard.

Now, armed with that model you can search online for a website from the manufacturer holding an update for your BIOS. Given the presumed age of your hardware this might no longer be possible and your next best option would be online forums. 
Alternatively there are Overclocking/Hardware groups/enthusiasts that can perhaps furnish you with a modded BIOS file for you to flash onto your motherboard that while not official might perhaps expose the functionality that you require. This of course requires some searching online on your part.